# wxPython wx.Frame with wx.Dialog effect

Tags: dialog, wxpython, frame

I want to have a wx.Frame that has the effect that the wx.Dialog has, that you cant unfocus it until it closes itself, makes it above all other. I need to use wx.Frame and not wx.Dialog because when using wx.Dialog and calling the dialog.ShowModal() it doesn't continue the code after it until the answer. I tried this:

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS,self.unfocus)`

```
def unfocus(self,e):
    self.SetFocuse()
```

But it didn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `MakeModal()`. So in your frame's class, you would call something like this:

```
self.MakeModal(True)
```

This only applies to wxPython classic. If you happen to be using Phoenix, then you'll want to take a look at the Migration Guide as `MakeModal` was removed:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#makemodal